# What can I do about missing Content-Type header when using html_session()?

Tags: r, rvest

I've been running this code successfully for some time:

```
pgsession <- html_session("https://example.com")
pgform <- html_form(pgsession)[[1]]
filledForm <- set_values(pgform, "userid" = "usr", "password" = "pwd")
submit_form(pgsession, filledForm)
x <-jump_to(pgsession, url)
```

However, it just broke; looks like the page has been updated? Anyway, I'm getting "***Error: Current page doesn't appear to be html***".

I poked around in the [code for html_session() on github](https://github.com/earino/rvest/blob/master/R/session.R), and I'm thinking the problem is a lack of Content-Type header.

I tried manually adding a header:

```
  if(is.null(pgsession$response$headers$`Content-Type`)) {
    pgsession$response$headers$`Content-Type` <- "text/html; charset=utf-8"
  }
```

but it didn't work. Probably the wrong approach in the first place to update a response header, but I couldn't think of anything else to do.

Can anyone help? Thanks.

**UPDATE:**

Well, based on feedback below I tried adding `httr::content_type("text/html")`, to the `html_session()` call, but it doesn't seem to add anything to the headers. I also looked a little closer and saw a `<nav>` element. So I see now the page is HTML 5. I then ran it through an online HTML validator. There are errors, but they seem minor.

Does rvest not support HTML 5? I have v0.3.2, which seems to be the latest. Should I switch to using httr directly? I need to log in and navigate, so rvest seemed very convenient.

Comment: You can pass `httr::content_type` to `html_session`, but if the data is not actually HTML for some reason, you'll still have problems when you try to pass it to `read_html`.

Comment: Ah, I saw "Any additional httr config to use throughout session" in the html_session docs, but glossed over it; I"m somewhat of a noob in R. Postman seems to parse the response as html, so this should work. I'll try this. Thank, mon ami.

Comment: No love, @alistaire. See above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more research and experimentation, I found that the problem is indeed that rvest's `html_form()` checks internally for a Content-Type header in order to declare the HTML in the `hmtl_session` as valid. This of course won't work for HTML 5, which uses a `<meta>` tag instead.

Bottom line: html_form() isn't going to support HTML 5 without Content-Type headers until this is fixed.

I reported the issue to rvest [here](https://github.com/hadley/rvest/issues/192), which also contains a workaround.